# Respons.js in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, responsive-design

I would love to perform some media queries for my SP 2010 website. As such i hoped that my problem would be solved using the js script of respons.js. However i cannot get it to work !

I should note that due to the polciy of our mother company I cannot use the SP designer thus cannot create / modify master pages etc (e.g. to put script linking in the header instead of the body) . Only tool i have is the online editor where i can use html and add js/css using the content editor.

So in my little project i have the following items (in this order):

1) content editor linked to css-loader.txt

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/SiteAssets/Code/CSS-Homepage.css" />
```

2) content editor linked to response.txt (added script tags in the txt file)

3) some html coding

//coding part of the content editors//

```
<div id="Filip"><h2>Filip de Clippel </h2></div>
```

My css file looks like :

```
@charset "utf-8";
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { #Filip {background-color: #006666;}}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) { #Filip {background-color: #333300;}}
```

But somehow I cannot get it to work. I tried

- List item playing with delaying the js by putting a window.onload function.
- List item min-width: 600px vs. min-width : 600px
- List item Adding media="screen" to my css-loader.txt file
- List item Many other things ;(

If someone could help me out or at least give me a hint in the good direction that would be so helpfull. Thnaks for all the efforts

Grtz

Comment: instead of: `@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { #Filip {background-color: #006666;}}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) { #Filip {background-color: #333300;}}`
 try: `@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { #Filip {background-color: #006666;}}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { #Filip {background-color: #333300;}}`

Comment: Using max-width only did not help unfortunately

Comment: The issue here for me is you are using `600px` for both `min-width` and `max-width` queries. It gets conflicted

Comment: well i used max-width: 900px and 1200px and although it might be part of the solution it is still not working Thansk for the efforts thinking together with me on this one as i've stuck on this thing for quite some hours ;s

Comment: Are you able to provide a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4e8x1vnm/2/

Comment: I run IE 9.0 And sharepoint 2010

Comment: UPDATE: I used the uncompressed min version of respond and now it does work in Chrome (39.0.2171.95 m) BUT still not in IE 9.0 
Getting closer at least

Comment: The sharepoint masterpage forces IE9.0 to be run in compatibility mode (i.e. IE8) . A common issues seems to be the security level to solve the issue of IE8.0 not working with repond.js But unfortunately unchecking the box  "enable protected mode" dit not help in my case

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="en-us" dir="ltr">
<head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /><meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" /><meta name="progid" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" /><title>

Comment: change `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">; ` to `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I cannot i'm affraid as my company policy does not allow me to change master pages in sharepoint. Someway to get around ?

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess it would solve your problem.

Comment: hope i can fiind a way without needing to edit anything outside the body tags ;S